# WinServer2008R2 refused "unsigned driver" however same driver works on other machines

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, 64-bit, drivers

Trying to load Silicon Labs CP210x USB to UART Bridge driver on my Windows Server 2008 R2 machine. Driver used is official release from Silicon Labs.

Stuck with error "Windows cannot verify the digital signature for the drivers required for this device. A recent hardware or software change might have installed a file that is signed incorrectly or damaged, or that might be malicious software from an unknown source. (Code 52)"

Same driver on another machine loads and works just fine.  Went through and completely nuked all driver files and registry entries, reloaded, and same issue occurs.

Anyone run into a similar situation?  I know I can F8 and disable signing check, but I don't want to have to do that every reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you should check that the system has all windows updates - if it doesn't have the correct root certificates then it will be unable to verify the driver signature.

Secondly if you are unable to work around this issue another way you can permanently allow unsigned drivers using

```
bcdedit -set loadoptions DISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS
bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING ON
```

Comment: The solution was to make sure all Windows updates were applied then remove and reinstall the drivers.